# nodejs electronjs sqlite3 - use of undeclared identifier 'napi_is_detached_arraybuffer'

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm, electron

I am trying to build a cross-platform app using electronjs and sqlite3.
I am getting following napi error. Tried to look around on internet, not much success.
node version = v14.15.5
npm version = 6.14.11
electronjs = electron@11.2.3

> In file included from /private/var/folders/fn/w2twbxf91x383fdq967zkl8r0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/iBigDo-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-addon-api/napi.h:2636:
> /private/var/folders/fn/w2twbxf91x383fdq967zkl8r0000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-x64/myapp-darwin-x64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/sqlite3/node_modules/node-addon-api/napi-inl.h:1575:24: error:
> use of undeclared identifier 'napi_is_detached_arraybuffer'; did you mean 'napi_is_arraybuffer'?
> napi_status status = napi_is_detached_arraybuffer(_env, _value, &detached);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> napi_is_arraybuffer

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hit the same error, and found that downgrading sqlite3 from 5.0.3 to 5.0.0 resolved it for me.